# Как сделать такую полоску под блоками?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь сверстать вот такой блок, который содержит в себе в ряд три блока выравненных по центру и имеющим на фоне такую "полоску". Сделал вот так, но `.frame::before` выходит за границы `.frame`. Как сделать чтобы `.frame::before` был шириной `100%` относительно `.frame`?

```css
.frame {
  width: 100%;
  height: 256px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 12px;
}
.block {
  height: 200px;
  width: 128px;
  background-color: chocolate;
  margin: 0 24px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  z-index: 0;
}
.frame::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 128px;
    /*! margin-top: 64px; */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.frame {
  width: 100%;
  height: 256px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 12px;
  position: relative;
}
.block {
  height: 200px;
  width: 128px;
  background-color: chocolate;
  margin: 0 24px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  z-index: 0;
}
.frame::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    /* width: 100%; */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 128px;
    /*! margin-top: 64px; */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```